# JQuery When second child is the last child, last-child doesn't work

Tags: jquery

```
 <ul>
      <li class="js"><span>JavaScript</span></li>
      <li class="js"><span>Python</span></li>
      <li class="jsa"><span>Swift</span></li>
 </ul>
```

see [link](http://jsbin.com/tipuroweko/edit?html,js,output) as well.

I don't know if my understanding about 'children' is correct, but in this situation, I think JavaScript and Python are two children of elements with class being 'js'. Using `$('li').filter('li.js:first-child')` I can get 'JavaScript', but I can't get 'Python' using `$('li').filter('li.js:last-child')`.

So I think this sort of proves that 'JavaScript' and 'Python' are children of elements with class 'js'

However, what is weird for me is that when I make 'Swift' have class 'js',

```
 <ul>
      <li class="js"><span>JavaScript</span></li>
      <li class="js"><span>Python</span></li>
      <li class="js"><span>Swift</span></li>
 </ul>
```

using `$('li').filter('li.js:last-child')` can get 'Swift'

Also, I know I can use :last by which I did get 'Python' when it's the second one and the last one at the same time. But I just don't understand why `:last-child` doesn't work for the same situation.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `:last-child` will filter all `<li>`s that are the last child of their parent, regardless whether you filter by `.js`

Comment: @Alex, thank you, now I see how last-child works. It took me a while to understand that. I thought it finds the last matched selector, so I think $('li.js:last-child') will return the last <li> with class 'js'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:last` instead of `last-child`, because `last-child` will look to the last-child of a parent container like `ul` which in your case is `.jsa` when you do it like you do now. Also, you shouldn't append `li` in `li` without `<ul>`, I mean you can, but it's not right.  Try this:

```js
//$('li').filter('li.js:last-child')
$('.js:last').click(function() {
  $('<li><span>C#</span></li>').appendTo($('li').filter('.js'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-div">
  <ul>
    <li class="js"><span>JavaScript</span>
    </li>
    <li class="js"><span>Python</span>
    </li>
    <li class="jsa"><span>Swift</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
Use `:last` because `last-child` select only the last-child of a parent:

<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @lonut, I didn't read API documentation very carefully so that I thought it finds the last matched selector, then I thought $('li.js:last-child') will return the last <li> with class 'js'.